# Xcode simulator shows up as being tiny

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am working on an iOS app in Xcode using Swift, and when I go to run the app in the simulator, it does not display as a normal simulation of the app that I am trying to run. The entire window is less than one inch by one inch, and shows what should be in the middle of the app. I ran it on my phone, and everything worked normally. Any insight into what may be going on? I'm developing the app using SpriteKit, if that provides and clues.

I have a bit of experience with iOS development, but I've never run into something like this before.

Edit: It only happens some of the time. I'm not sure, but I have a hunch that it is the result of some sort of race condition between GameScene and GameViewController

Comment: can you post screenshot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmd + 1 or Cmd + 2 should fix the size of the simulator (or Window -> Physical Size or Window -> Point Accurate).

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the size of the simulator. I'm still unsure about why this keeps happening and if it may be an indication of something wrong with my code, but that solves the immediate problem at least.

Comment: It is almost certainly just a bug you're experiencing. I can't think of a situation where the code would affect the size of the simulator. Glad I could help though! (btw you can press the check mark next to my answer to show that it solved your problem.)